# How to customize text In App Update? So we can explain them what's new or why user should update

Tags: android, in-app-update

How to customize text In App Update? So we can explain them what's new or why user should update

The current text is not so friendly

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quik fix. It seem the only way is the handle if there is an update and show my own dialog before let user see Google dialog with... Hopefully there is a way to show only one dialog by customize Google dialog